# IIS 4.0 URL Unsafe

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, .net-4.0

I have a URL used on a .NET IIS server.

http://10.61.65.108:8888/QQQQ/2011-06-23T00%3a00%3a00.0000000%2b08%3a00

I used HttpUtility.URLEncode to encode the values.

I get the error:

**A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).**

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx).